# Fonts on wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, azure, fonts

I am trying to get a custom font to work on my WordPress site which is using an already-built theme (hosted by azure). The theme has no option built-in to change/add a font. The font that I am using works on another website. The file format is `.oft` . I have disabled caching server side. I am able to change the font to different websafe fonts. I have tested accessing the site from different computers and browsers with stored pages disabled.

"Failed" means that I have preset all font to 'sans-serif' and when I try any of these method it overrides this back up and uses the browsers default instead.

I think this means there isn't any random `!important` in the css that im not aware of.

Here is what i have tried so far.

at the top of my css file:

```
@font-face{
 font-family:'FontName';    
 src:url('http://example.com/font.otf') format("opentype");/* tryed with an without format type*/
}
```

at the bottom of my css file:

```
  body{
        font-family: FontName;
    }
```

1. I have tried converted the file type to the 5 most popular formats and tried separately and together.
2. I have tried accessing the font from a different external server.
3. I have tried using `@import` to take the css from the working website to mine and use the created font-family to change the type.
4. I have tried accessing different custom font (including google fonts). this also failed.
5. I have tried 3 separate plugin for WordPress (including "use any font"(which has worked on other projects)) and they all failed.

After all these attempts I am not even sure where to continue looking for the fault. Any ideas even on general direction would be useful.

Comment: View your site in chrome. Press F12 and look at the console log. It may tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: In your example you're not really showing where you're trying to load a font from. Is it on your server or somewhere like Google Fonts?

Comment: Additionally, normally you need to load several font formats for full cross-browser compatibility.  Check out [fontsquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/) for more info.

Comment: ok im ideally trying to load the font from a server i control,  when this didn't work i tryed from another that i have loaded from in the past, when that didn't work i tried a generic google font to see if it was the font itself, (all failed)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing the MIME types in `web.config` (they're not in by default in App Service or vanilla IIS):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/opentype" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

Debug with **F12 → Network**.
You should get a `200 OK` for the font file(s).
`404 Not Found` if you're missing the MIME type(s).

LATER EDIT:

`.otf` is apparently now [`application/font-sfnt`](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/font-sfnt). If MIME type is really your problem, do some more research around the right type for this one.

Answer (score 1):

Upload You font inside the theme/fonts folder. I'm assuming that you have created fonts folder inside theme folder and upload the font file inside the fonts folder.

That time your code should be:

```
@font-face{
 font-family:'FontName';    
 src:url('fonts/font.otf') format("opentype");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the font file is hosted in the root directory of example.com

```
@font-face {
    font-family: FontName;    
    src: url('/font.otf');
}
```